# Yahoo Fantasy Sports API returning server error

Tags: yql, yahoo-api

I have been using the [Yahoo Fantasy Sports API](https://developer.yahoo.com/fantasysports/guide/) for several years now, but over the last 24 hours, I've been getting server errors.  Nothing has changed in my code, and other users are confirming similar issues [here](https://forums.yahoo.net/t5/Fantasy-Baseball/Yahoo-Fantasy-Sports-API-not-responding/m-p/246085#U246085).  The Yahoo support staff redirected us to their [YQL support](https://developer.yahoo.com/support/yql/) page, which tells people to post their questions on SO.  Has this API been silently killed?  Is there a new version?

Comment: If the error is a 500, you can't do much to resolve it (it signifies it's on their end), they're also likely the best source of information for updates/versions/fixes.

Comment: Yahoo! fixed the problem, and their fantasy sports API is working again. See [this post](https://forums.yahoo.net/t5/Fantasy-Baseball/Yahoo-Fantasy-Sports-API-not-responding/td-p/246085)
for more detail.

Comment: It seems the API is broken again.

Comment: @seanmk, looking okay to me right now...  *knocks on wood*  Perhaps just a temporary blip?

Comment: @tonycpsu I get server errors from most queries but not all.  For example, I cannot find the game id for the mlb 2018 season because the service returns 500 errors (http://fantasysports.yahooapis.com/fantasy/v2/game/mlb?season=2018).

Comment: WFM, @seanmk. (It's `378`, btw.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this issue and it seems that Yahoo has basically silently deprecated / removed support for oauth, so you have to switch to oauth2 to in order to use many of their APIs.

[Source](https://forums.yahoo.net/t5/Help-with-Fantasy-Baseball/Receiving-500-quot-Internal-Server-Error-quot-from-Yahoo-Fantasy/m-p/347199/highlight/true#M7680)

In my case the [`yahoo_oauth` python library](https://pypi.org/project/yahoo_oauth/) worked quite well for upgrading to 2.0.